# Is this problem really hard or programming is not for me

Tags: python, cs50

**when I can't solve the challenges without researching the solution I think maybe it's not for me**

In a file called fuel.py, implement a program that prompts the user for a fraction, formatted as X/Y, wherein each of X and Y is an integer, and then outputs, as a percentage rounded to the nearest integer, how much fuel is in the tank. If, though, 1% or less remains, output E instead to indicate that the tank is essentially empty. And if 99% or more remains, output F instead to indicate that the tank is essentially full.

If, though, X or Y is not an integer, X is greater than Y, or Y is 0, instead prompt the user again. (It is not necessary for Y to be 4.) Be sure to catch any exceptions like ValueError or ZeroDivisionError.

Hints

look at the photo to understand better
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJcSx.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  It feels like you're asking us to write the whole program for you...

Comment: Only time will tell if programming is for you. However, you can always start with what you know. Solve the problem on a piece of paper and write down each step that you take. The steps you take are developing an algorithm. Writing down the steps in English not a programming language is called pseudocode. Then of course, it will be necessary to learn the language of Python. However, Python is a very English-like language.

Comment: Don't be disheartened, everyone has to research solutions all the time - no one has the memory capactiy to have instant recall of all nuances of a programming language and its packages. The best way to learn is to start coding - have a go at the problem and then post your code for help

Comment: I have been coding for over four years now, and yet I still count Google as my best coding companion. Everyone has to research all the time.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't want the solution, there's already a solution on YouTube, I'm saying that this is what frustrates me, I couldn't solve it on my own, I don't want to be a copy and paste programmer, I want to be great, if not above average, no I will continue in this area

Comment: @Alan If you don't a solution, than could you clarify exactly what you are asking in your question?

Comment: when you say you couldn't solve it on your own, can you be more specific? what have you tried and can you show us any code you have written? if you're feeling overwhelmed by the whole problem, you can try starting smaller by `"writing a program that prompts the user for a fraction, formatted as X/Y, wherein each of X and Y is an integer"`. regardless, you'll need to add a bit more detail to your question or it'll likely be closed due to `needing more focus`

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning how the site works, I will post more objective questions next time and with codes @DerekO

Comment: @Alan no worries – just wanted to bring these points to your attention so that you get the answer you're looking for and your question doesn't get closed

Answer (score 2):

**Code:-**

```
x=input("Enter the value of x: ")
y=input("Enter the value of y: ")
try:
    x=float(x)
    y=float(y)
    res=(x/y)*100
    if res>=99:
        print("F")
    elif res<=1:
        print("E")
    else:
        print(str(round(res))+"%")
except ValueError:
    print("Value is not correct")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Value of y is 0")
```

**Output:-**

Testcase 1: **when divisor is 0** **(i.e when y is 0)**

```
Enter the value of x: 4
Enter the value of y: 0
Value of y is 0
```

Testcase 2: **when value is not a number.**

```
Enter the value of x: 4
Enter the value of y: w
Value is not correct
```

Testcase 3: **Nearly to 1% or less.**

```
Enter the value of x: 0.001
Enter the value of y: 4
E
```

Testcase 4: **Nearly to 99% or more.**

```
Enter the value of x: 3.999
Enter the value of y: 4
F
```

Testcase 5: **when % is b/w (1,99)** **both exculsive**

```
Enter the value of x: 3
Enter the value of y: 4
75%
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants or needs a complete solution to the question – they either want general guidance on how the approach the problem or help at a point where they're stuck